# Images not showing - Rails 4 (using Paperclip gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to get images to upload as flyers for events. I do have the parameters configured in the controller. No error is being shown, but the actual image is not rendering in the view (all you see is the filename).

When I upload an image file in production (hosting with Heroku) it saves properly and I can see the file name and size in the console. I can even go to my Amazon S3 console and look at the actual image from there.

This makes it hard for me to tell what's wrong.

I have a hunch that I'm about to try out (among many other things). The only thing I think it could be is that I haven't configured the url to the location of the file in my S3 bucket, but so far I haven't found out exactly how to do that...

In case you're wondering, I do believe I have the code for the view, controller, and model written properly. But the model does make me curious. Here it is just in case:

event.rb

```
has_attached_file :flyer,
                  styles: { medium: '300x430#', thumb: '123x170#' }

validates_attachment_content_type :flyer, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

private

def flyer_size
    if flyer.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:flyer, 'must be less than 5MB')
    end
end
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

EDIT:

When I inspect element this is what it shows.

```
    <img src= "https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucketname]/events/flyers/000/000/008/medium/JAM.jpg?1436400492" alt="Jam" >
::before
</img>
```

Comment: What does inspect element shows? I think your html.erb code might be missing the correct url

Comment: Inspect element shows this

    <img src= "https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucketname]/events/flyers/000/000/008/medium/JAM.jpg?1436400492" alt="Jam" >
::before
</img>

Comment: And do you get a 404 error in console or this link is actually valid?